# When running a task from TYPO3 scheduler it is executed but it is not executed from the command line

Tags: shell, typo3, task, scheduler

When I run the task from a console with:

```
typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run
```

nothing happens. No errors and no mail. The path to PHP is in my search path so that is not the problem. When I run the task from the TYPO3 BE the task get executed as expected. Also after the task should be executed based on the time scheme of the scheduler a sign `late` appears.
Does anybody know why executing the scheduler task from a console doesn't work.

I use TYPO3 9.5.14. My code in `ext_localconf.php`:

```
// Register handler calls for Scheduler
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['scheduler']['tasks’][\Vendor\Extensionname\Command\SyncCommand::class] = [
    'extension' => 'verwijswijzer',
    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:verwijswijzer/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:scheduler.title',
    'description' => 'LLL:EXT:verwijswijzer/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:scheduler.description'
];
```

and in `Classes/Command/SyncCommand.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Extensionname\Command;

use TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use Vendor\Extensionname\Task\StoreRecords;


class SyncCommand extends AbstractTask {

    public $email="email@dnaklik.nl";

    public function execute()

    {

        $exec = $this->getExecution();
        // Get call method
        if (Environment::isCli()) {
            $calledBy = 'CLI module dispatcher';
            $site = '-';
        } else {
            $calledBy = 'TYPO3 backend';
            $site = GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_URL');
        }
        $start = $exec->getStart();
        $end = $exec->getEnd();
        $interval = $exec->getInterval();
        $multiple = $exec->getMultiple();
        $cronCmd = $exec->getCronCmd();
        $mailBody = 'Some content');
        // Prepare mailer and send the mail
        try {
            /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage $mailer */
            $mailer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage::class);
            $mailer->setFrom([$this->email => 'SCHEDULER GGZ-API-TASK']);
            $mailer->setReplyTo([$this->email => 'SCHEDULER GGZ-API-TASK']);
            $mailer->setSubject('SCHEDULER GGZ-API-TASK');
            $mailer->setBody($mailBody);
            $mailer->setTo($this->email);
            $mailsSend = $mailer->send();
            $success = $mailsSend > 0;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception($e->getMessage(), 1476048416);
        }

        $execTask = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyTask::class );
        $execTask->run();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd check if the PHP interpreter used on the command line is the same as the interpreter used by the web server. This is not always the same PHP binary and in some hosting environments even a different PHP version. The same applies to the PHP configuration. PHP on the CLI can use a different `php.ini` file for example.

Comment: It is the same php interpreter. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just after I posted this question I suddenly also received an email when the task was run from the command line. No idea why. Maybe a cache issue.